# How to do flashing rectangle outline for a WPF datagrid cell?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation, datagrid

Basically I have a WPF datagrid, and I want to add a flashing outline to a specific cell in XAML via binding that will make this visible. I know how to do this except the flashing part.

How can I do that so that the rectangle outline flashes for a specific duration like 2 seconds, so it goes from opacity = 0 to 1 and then 0 and so on.

Does WPF have a mechanism for this?

```xml
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red">
        <Rectangle Fill="#FF5A9AE0"
                   Stretch="UniformToFill"
                   ClipToBounds="True"/>
    </Border>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will flash the border on and off.

```xml
    <Border Name="MyBorder" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red">
        <Border.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                            Storyboard.TargetName="MyBorder" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness"
                            AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <DiscreteThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:00.00" Value="1" />
                            <DiscreteThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:00.25" Value="5" />
                            <DiscreteThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:00.50" Value="1" />
                        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Border.Triggers>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FF5A9AE0" Stretch="UniformToFill" ClipToBounds="True" />
    </Border>
```

There are lots of animation options, so please have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/animation-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8 for details/ideas.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. When I change the values live in VS, they don't update immediately. I have to restart each time, but it's not a big deal.

Comment: Also I am trying to find info on the keytime, I know the 3rd one is seconds, but what's the forth one? 25 is 1/4th of a second?

Comment: @JoanVenge - Yes, the seconds value is decimal, so 0:0:00.25 means 1/4 second. Not sure what you mean about the values not updating immediately in VS.

Comment: thx. i mean when i modify XAML while the app is running under VS debugging the animation timing doesn't update. It takes effect after restating the app.